# Typescript: How to sort an array by multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have a array of unsorted "Edition" objects.

```
export interface Edition {
  name: string;
  edition_code: string;
  parent_code: string;
  released_at: number;
}
```

The attributes `name`, `edition_code` and `released_at` are set on every object. The attribute `parent_code` can be null.

An edition object with no `parent_code` is a parent edition. All edition objects where the `parent_code` is equal to the parent edition's `edition_code` are child editions of this parent edition.

I try to sort an array by the following conditions:

- All parent editions must be sorted by `released_at` (newest first)

  - A parent edition can have zero ore more child editions
- Every child edition has to be sorted directy after the matching parent edition object. (ignoring the `released_at`attribute)

  - The child editions must be sorted alphabetically by their names.

I am trying to sort the array with the `sort()` method. The `allEditions()`-method returns an `Observable<Array<Edition>>`

```
this.dataSource = this.editionService.allEditions().pipe(
      map((editions) =>
        editions
          .sort((a, b) => {
            // this is the point where i struggle to create the correct sorting function
          })
      )
    );
```

**Example:**

This is an example of an unsorted array:

```
[
{
  "name": "Stomper";
  "edition_code": "sto";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Flyer";
  "edition_code": "fly";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1619128800000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Promos";
  "edition_code": "psto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Ultra";
  "edition_code": "usto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Flyer Special";
  "edition_code": "sfly";
  "parent_code": "fly";
  "released_at": "1619128800000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Extras";
  "edition_code": "esto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Roller";
  "edition_code": "rol";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1374184800000";
},
{
  "name": "Flyer Reloaded";
  "edition_code": "rfly";
  "parent_code": "fly";
  "released_at": "1493330400000";
}
]
```

This is the exact same array but sorted:

```
[
{
  "name": "Flyer";
  "edition_code": "fly";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1619128800000";
},
{
  "name": "Flyer Reloaded";
  "edition_code": "rfly";
  "parent_code": "fly";
  "released_at": "1493330400000";
},
{
  "name": "Flyer Special";
  "edition_code": "sfly";
  "parent_code": "fly";
  "released_at": "1619128800000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper";
  "edition_code": "sto";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Extras";
  "edition_code": "esto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Promos";
  "edition_code": "psto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Stomper Ultra";
  "edition_code": "usto";
  "parent_code": "sto";
  "released_at": "1587679200000";
},
{
  "name": "Roller";
  "edition_code": "rol";
  "parent_code": null;
  "released_at": "1374184800000";
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sort` function isn't what you want here. Or at least not just one single sort function.

Here's your work flow:

1. make a filtered list that ONLY includes parent editions. sort this by 'released at'
2. make a filtered list that ONLY includes child editions. sort this by name.
3. make a brand new empty array. Iterate over your parent list. Foreach parent list, put the parent item into the array, THEN find all matching child items and put them into the array right after.

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense and I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how sort() can solve my problem until now